# What is the best term to describe a "native English speaker who is an American"?

Tags: terminology

When applying for English teaching jobs, I want to describe myself as a "native speaker of English who has an American accent" since most companies in Europe want native speakers to teach English courses and they usually have a preference for one accent or another (American, British, Australian, etc.).

What is the best term for this, e.g. "I am a...":

- American native speaker of English (good?)
- American English native speaker (good?)
- native speaker of American English (best?)
- native American English speaker ("native American" could be confused with being an American Indian)

Comment: I'd stay away from using the words "Native American" unless you are a member of one of the many American Indian tribes.

Comment: I would be as specific as possible. Write something like "I speak American English with a (southern/midwestern/northern/eastern) accent, having grown up in that region." Wouldn't want to come across as something you're not nor force the interviewer to decipher your intent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"American English native speaker" actually sounds a bit odd to me, though I am not a native speaker of American English myself.

I would go with "native speaker of American English", as I have just done. If you read [nohat](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat)'s full disclosure, he seems to agree.

*Edit:* I see that you have edited your question, so you seem to agree yourself now that "native speaker of American English" is the way to go.

One more thing: I read "American native speaker of English" as "someone who is a native speaker of English and lives in the US". That could easily apply to a native Scot who moved to the States.

Comment: I agree that "native speaker of American English" is the best answer if you really want to say both "American" and "native English speaker". But it you say simply "American", I guess that it is implicit that you're a native English speaker.

Comment: +1 yes, "native speaker of American English" is what sounded the best for me after writing all these out, and thanks for the link to @nohat's profile, if that's what he uses, that's what I'll use, he seems to be the Jon Skeet of this site. :-)

Comment: @Bruno I know many Americans who are not native speakers of English, e.g. many children of Americans growing up in non-English-speaking countries who hold an American passport just the same. Also many of the grandparents of children I grew up with were not native English speakers, and I'm sure many legal immigrants who are Americans today are not native English speakers.

Comment: @Edward Tanguay, yes, that's a good point.

Comment: @Edward Tanguay Don't forget we're talking about English teaching jobs though! :D

Comment: @Bruno You are entirely correct, I think saying "American" is sufficient for most situations. However, there are Americans who don't speak English, and technically there are also "native speakers of American English" who are not U.S. citizens (born overseas to U.S. parents, or renounced citizenship).

Comment: As far as I know, who was born outside USA, and his father is American (it is probably valid also if his mother is American), is an American citizen. Probably he has two citizenship, but for sure he doesn't lose his American citizenship (if he doesn't renounce to it). Who was not born on American territory cannot become President of USA, but he is still American citizen.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you are **"an American, with English as a mother language"**.

You could therefore say that you **"have American English as your mother language"** or you could say that your **"mother language is American English"**.

Freely substitute "mother" with "native" and substitute "language" with "tongue". Therefore, all the following are valid:

- "an American, with English as a native language"
- "have American English as your native language"
- "native language is American English"
- "an American, with English as a native tongue"
- "have American English as your native tongue"
- "native tongue is American English"
- "an American, with English as a mother language"
- "have American English as your mother language"
- "mother language is American English"
- "an American, with English as a mother tongue"
- "have American English as your mother tongue"
- "mother tongue is American English"

Answer (score 0):

Our home dictionary proclaimed to be of the American language, but I feel that is overstating the differences.  What we speak is a form of English, since it shares the majority of the words and structure.

Your question is what to call yourself depends on who is asking. "I am an American" usually works if you are white, but if you aren't, some folks want more of an explanation.  In China, were I taught, Americans with Chinese heritage were called "overseas Chinese".  If you are trying to secure a teaching or translating job then use "native English speaker from America."